# es6 import. is there any way to use `namespace` as `class` in `generics`?

Tags: typescript, generics

```
// `./module.ts`
export class User
{
    name: string
    surname: string
    age: number
}
```

### es6 import

`import * as module from "./module"` generate `namespace module` and this is bad.

1. call `typeof module` brakes `class generics` from `module`:

   > type `User` is not assignable to parameter of type `typeof User`
2. this `module` can't be extended by another `namespace module {}` or `interface module {}`  call.

### Q:

- is there any way to use `namespace` as `class` in generics ?
- is there any way to export many classes from module as class type without handmade associations?

---

```
namespace _0.A - real behavior
namespace _0.B - expected behavior
namespace _1.extend - extend expected behavior
```

look in [typescriptlang.org/play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2F%20import%20%7B%20User%20%7D%20from%20%22.%2Fmodule%22%0A%2F%2F%20import%20*%20as%20module%20from%20%22.%2Fmodule%22%0A%2F%2F%20equal%20this%3A%0Aclass%20User%0A%7B%0A%09name%3A%20string%0A%09surname%3A%20string%0A%09age%3A%20number%0A%7D%0Anamespace%20module%0A%7B%0A%09export%20class%20User%0A%09%7B%0A%09%09name%3A%20string%0A%09%09surname%3A%20string%0A%09%09age%3A%20number%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Anamespace%20_0.A%0A%7B%0A%09type%20m%20%3D%20typeof%20module%3B%0A%09type%20user%20%3D%20m%5B'User'%5D%20%20%20%2F%2F%20err%20%2F%2F%20type%20user%20%3D%20typeof%20User%0A%09let%20age%3A%20user%5B'age'%5D%20%20%20%2F%2F%20err%20%2F%2F%20%5Bts%5D%20Property%20'age'%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20type%20'typeof%20User'.%0A%7D%0Anamespace%20_0.B%0A%7B%0A%09class%20m%0A%09%7B%0A%09%09User%3A%20User%0A%09%7D%0A%09type%20user%20%3D%20m%5B'User'%5D%20%20%20%2F%2F%20ok%20%2F%2F%20type%20user%20%3D%20User%0A%09let%20age%3A%20user%5B'age'%5D%20%20%20%2F%2F%20ok%20%2F%2F%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Anamespace%20_1%0A%7B%0A%09let%20store%20%3D%20%7B%7D%0A%09type%20store%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0A%09%09%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20T%5BK%5D%5B%5D%0A%09%7D%0A%09export%20function%20set%3CT%3E(k%3A%20keyof%20T%2C%20val%3A%20T%5Bkeyof%20T%5D)%0A%09%7B%0A%09%09(store%20as%20store%3CT%3E)%5Bk%5D.push(val)%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Anamespace%20_1.A%0A%7B%0A%09type%20mo%20%3D%20typeof%20module%3B%0A%09%2F%2F%20--%0A%09set%3Cmo%3E('User'%2C%20new%20User)%20%2F%2F%20%5Bts%5D%20Argument%20of%20type%20'User'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20parameter%20of%20type%20'typeof%20User'.%0A%7D%0Anamespace%20_1.B%0A%7B%0A%09class%20mo%0A%09%7B%0A%09%09User%3A%20User%0A%09%7D%0A%09%2F%2F%20--%0A%09set%3Cmo%3E('User'%2C%20new%20User)%0A%7D%0A%0Anamespace%20_1.extend%0A%7B%0A%09class%20mo%0A%09%7B%0A%09%09User%3A%20User%0A%09%7D%0A%09class%20Admin%0A%09%7B%0A%09%09superpover%3A%20true%0A%09%7D%0A%09class%20moExt%20extends%20mo%0A%09%7B%0A%09%09Admin%3A%20Admin%0A%09%7D%0A%09%2F%2F%20--%0A%09set%3CmoExt%3E('Admin'%2C%20new%20Admin)%0A%7D%0A) or read next

---

```
// import { User } from "./module"
// import * as module from "./module"
// equal this:
class User
{
  name: string
  surname: string
  age: number
}
namespace module
{
  export class User
  {
    name: string
    surname: string
    age: number
  }
}

namespace _1
{
  let store = {}
  type store<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K][]
  }
  export function set<T>(k: keyof T, val: T[keyof T])
  {
    if (!(store as store<T>)[k]) (store as store<T>)[k] = [];
    (store as store<T>)[k].push(val)
  }
}

namespace _1.A
{
  type mo = typeof module;
  // --
  set<mo>('User', new User) // [ts] Argument of type 'User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'typeof User'.
}
namespace _1.B
{
  class mo
  {
    User: User
  }
  // --
  set<mo>('User', new User) // ok
}

namespace _1.extend
{
  class Admin
  {
    superpover: true
  }
  // --
  class mo
  {
    User: User
  }
  class moExt extends mo
  {
    Admin: Admin
  }
  // --
  set<moExt>('Admin', new Admin)
}

namespace _0.A
{
  type m = typeof module;
  type user = m['User']   // bad // type user = typeof User
  let age: user['age']   // err // [ts] Property 'age' does not exist on type 'typeof User'.
}
namespace _0.B
{
  class m
  {
    User: User
  }
  type user = m['User']   // good // type user = User
  let age: user['age']   // ok   //
}
```

---

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### solution

```
type Convert<T> = {
    [k in keyof T]: T[k] extends { new(): infer R }
    ? R
    : T[k]
}
```

---

full sample code, in the context of the question, look there [typescriptlang.org/play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F**%0Aimportant!%0A%0ABAD%0A%3Ct%20extends%20Convert%3Ctt%3E%2C%20k%20extends%20keyof%20t%3E%0A%0AGOOD%0A%3Ct%20extends%20Convert%3Ctt%3E%2C%20k%20extends%20keyof%20Convert%3Ctt%3E%3E%0A%0A%20*%2F%0A%0Atype%20Convert%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0A%09%5Bk%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20T%5Bk%5D%20extends%20%7B%20new()%3A%20infer%20R%20%7D%0A%09%3F%20R%0A%09%3A%20T%5Bk%5D%0A%7D%0A%0Anamespace%20module%0A%7B%0A%09export%20class%20User%0A%09%7B%0A%09%09name%3A%20string%0A%09%09surname%3A%20string%0A%09%09age%3A%20number%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Anamespace%20_1%0A%7B%0A%09export%20let%20store%20%3D%20%7B%7D%0A%09export%20type%20store%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0A%09%09%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20T%5BK%5D%5B%5D%0A%09%7D%0A%09export%20function%20set%3CT%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E(k%3A%20K%2C%20val%3A%20T%5BK%5D)%0A%09%7B%0A%09%09if%20(!(store%20as%20store%3CT%3E)%5Bk%5D)%20(store%20as%20store%3CT%3E)%5Bk%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%09%09(store%20as%20store%3CT%3E)%5Bk%5D.push(val)%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0Atype%20t1%20%3D%20Convert%3Ctypeof%20module%3E%3B%0A%2F%2F%20_1.set%3Ct1%2C%20keyof%20t1%3E('User'%2C%20'-%2C-')%20%2F%2F%20%5Bts%5D%20Argument%20of%20type%20'%22-%2C-%22'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20parameter%20of%20type%20'User'.%0A_1.set%3Ct1%2C%20keyof%20t1%3E('User'%2C%20new%20module.User)%0A%0A%0A%2F%2F%20---%20extend%0Aclass%20Admin%0A%7B%0A%09superpover%3A%20true%0A%7D%0Aclass%20moExt%0A%7B%0A%09Admin%3A%20Admin%0A%7D%0Anamespace%20qqw%0A%7B%0A%09export%20var%20qqwkey%3A%20%5Bnumber%2C%20string%5D%0A%7D%0Atype%20t2%20%3D%20Convert%3Ctypeof%20module%20%26%20moExt%20%26%20typeof%20qqw%3E%3B%0A%2F%2F%20--%20or%0A%2F%2F%20type%20t2%20%3D%20Convert%3Ctypeof%20module%3E%20%26%20moExt%20%26%20Convert%3Ctypeof%20qqw%3E%3B%0A_1.set%3Ct2%2C%20keyof%20t2%3E('Admin'%2C%20'-%2C-')%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20err%20%2F%2F%20good%0A_1.set%3Ct2%2C%20keyof%20t2%3E('Admin'%2C%20new%20module.User)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20ok%20%20%2F%2F%20bad%20%0A_1.set%3Ct2%2C%20keyof%20t2%3E('Admin'%2C%20new%20Admin)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20ok%20%20%2F%2F%20good%0A_1.set%3Ct2%2C%20keyof%20t2%3E('Admin'%2C%20%7B%20superpover%3A%20true%20%7D)%20%20%2F%2F%20ok%20%20%2F%2F%20good%0A%0A_1.set%3Ct2%2C%20keyof%20t2%3E('qqwkey'%2C%20%7B%20superpover%3A%20true%20%7D)%20%2F%2F%20ok%20%20%2F%2F%20bad%0A%0A%0A%2F%2F%20---%20fix%20funcion%0Alet%20set2%3A%20%3CT%20extends%20t2%2C%20k%20extends%20keyof%20t2%3E(k%3A%20k%2C%20val%3A%20T%5Bk%5D)%20%3D%3E%20void%0A%0Aset2('Admin'%2C%20'-%2C-')%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20err%20%20%2F%2F%20good%0Aset2('Admin'%2C%20new%20module.User)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20err%20%20%2F%2F%20good%0Aset2('Admin'%2C%20new%20Admin)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20ok%20%20%20%2F%2F%20good%0Aset2('Admin'%2C%20%7B%20superpover%3A%20true%20%7D)%20%20%2F%2F%20ok%20%20%20%2F%2F%20good%0A%0Aset2('qqwkey'%2C%20%7B%20superpover%3A%20true%20%7D)%20%2F%2F%20err%20%20%2F%2F%20good%0Aset2('qqwkey'%2C%20%5B''%2C''%5D)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20err%20%20%2F%2F%20good%0Aset2('qqwkey'%2C%20%5B17%2C''%5D)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20ok%20%20%20%2F%2F%20good%0A)

---